# How to read Androids CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH width/height?

Tags: java, android, api, video

As I want to set up Androids camcorder recording quality via CamcorderProfiles (`CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH`/LOW) I also need to set up cameras preview size (and layout) accordingly. How can I read actual width/height of the recording profile I specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a CamcorderProfile:

```
CamcorderProfile cm = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P);
```

you can get the videoFrameWidth/Height:

```
int width = cm.videoFrameWidth
int height = cm.videoFrameHeight
```

Now if I could only get the rest of my video camera working... :(

Comment: thanks for that, I figured it already but that is correct answer